# pushviewcontroller not working because self.navigationController is null

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a big problem: on method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I always get null to self.navigationController. I have a UIViewController that contains a UIsegmentedControl and a subView. On this subView I add the controllers for each segment selected. For each segment a have a tableview. Here is the problem: when I select a row from this tableview I can't do push for next controller because self.navigationController is null.

Please help me..Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/qq0vf7mq

without the code :

```
navigationTelephone=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.navigationTelephone.view];
    [self.navigationTelephone setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:tableViewTelephone];
```

Comment: Your app is navigation based or any other based app

Answer (score 0):

I think You have initialize the  UINavigationController like below

```
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ViewControllerOBj]
```

Comment: I wrote navigationTelephone=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myAudiCoordonneesViewController]; but I get Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController :>

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

You initialize an instance variable `navigationTelephone` and display it, but you use `self.navigationController` to push!
Use `[navigationTelephone push...]` instead

Comment: I have it but it doesn't work...is not pushing to next viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    myAudiPhoneInputViewController *myViewController = [[myAudiPhoneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIB NAME HERE" bundile:nil];
    self.myaudiPhoneInputViewController = myViewController;
    [myViewController release];

    [tableViewTelephone deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if(indexPath.row==0){

        NSLog(@"Tel.personnel... %@",self.navigationTelephone);


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myaudiPhoneInputViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

You haven't instantiate your myaudiPhoneViewController that is why it's not pushing the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just check by changing,

```
self.navigationTelephone=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
```

Naveen Shan